# Проблема при изменении пароля в MySql

Tags: mysql, cmd

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin>mysqld.exe 
--default-file="my.ini" --init-file="C:\\Users\\Maks\\Desktop\\mysql-init.txt" --console
```

> > mysqld: Can't change dir to 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server5.7\data\' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
> >
> > > 2016-08-01T09:12:57.308800Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
> > >       2016-08-01T09:12:57.308800Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
> > >       2016-08-01T09:12:57.308800Z 0 [Note] mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.7.11) starting as process 9604 ...
> > >       2016-08-01T09:12:57.311799Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\data\Ma_PC.lower-test
> > >       2016-08-01T09:12:57.312799Z 0 [Warning] Can't create test file C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\data\Ma_PC.lower-test
> > >       2016-08-01T09:12:57.314799Z 0 [ERROR] failed to set datadir to C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\data\
> > >       2016-08-01T09:12:57.329799Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
> > >       2016-08-01T09:12:57.330799Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
> > >       2016-08-01T09:12:57.331799Z 0 [Note] mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete

- Если кто сможет помочь разобраться с ошибками, буду рад! Непонятно, в чём ошибка!

Answer (score 1):

У вас сервер mysqld ищет обращается к несуществующему каталогу данных в

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server5.7\data\
```

Вообще MySQL там его и не должна держать, она старается вынести его в пользовательский каталог текущего пользователя. Проверьте в my.ini корректное ли значение у директивы `datadir`. Если такой директивы вообще нет, найдите каталог данных и пропишите в директиве `datadir` явно.